# Transfer of objects b/w Client/Server using UDP

Tags: c++, udp, client-server

I want to send an object from server to client. Through UDP. In c++. I tried to simply send a reference to client and make a pointer in client to refer to this address. Code for what I tried is:

data:

```
class data
{
private:
    int number;
public:
    data(int number) {
        this->number = number;
    }
    void print() {
        cout<<"number : "<<number;
    }
};
```

server:

```
data *obj;
if (recvfrom(conn_sock, obj, sizeof(data), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &slen) == -1)
    cout<<"ERROR: recvfrom()";
else cout<<"SUCCESS: recvfrom()";

cout<<"\nRECEIVED from Client : ";
obj->print();
```

client:

```
data *obj = new data(11);
if(sendto(conn_sock, &obj, sizeof(data), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, addr_len) == -1)
    cout<<"ERROR: Problem sending data";
else cout<<"SUCCESS: sending object";
```

Comment: You can't just send a reference to an object over the network. If the client is on another machine, it has no way of accessing the memory of the server's machine and will not be able to access the object. I suggest you break down the information inside the object into bytes, send it, parse it at the client and create the object from the parsed information.

Comment: yes, you're right. I didn't considered that thing. My client and server were on the same machine that's why I was doing it this way. Now I got my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the problem. I did just as @snixtho suggested. The working code is:

data:

```
class data
{
private:
    int number;
    float gpa;
public:
    data(int number, float gpa) {
        this->number = number;
    }
    void print() {
        cout<<"number : "<<number<<"gpa : "<<gpa;
    }
    int getNumber() {
        return this->number;
    }
    int getGpa() {
        return this->number;
    }
};
```

server:

```
data *obj;
int number = 0;
float gpa = 0.0;

if (recvfrom(conn_sock, buf, buff_length, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &slen) == -1)
    cout<<"ERROR: recvfrom()";
number = atoi(buf);

if (recvfrom(conn_sock, buf, buff_length, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &slen) == -1)
    cout<<"ERROR: recvfrom()";
gpa = atoi(buf);

obj = new data(number, gpa);

cout<<"\nRECEIVED from Client : ";
obj->print();
cout<<"\n\n";
```

client:

```
data *obj = new data(11, 3.2);
int n=0;    // n is the number of bytes of 'buf' after converting the integer to 'buf'

n = sprintf(buf, "%d", obj->getNumber());  
if(sendto(conn_sock, buf, buff_length, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, addr_len) == -1)
    cout<<"ERROR: Problem sending data";

n = sprintf(buf, "%f", obj->getGpa());
if(sendto(conn_sock, buf, buff_length, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, addr_len) == -1)
    cout<<"ERROR: Problem sending data";
```

This is solving the problem, but I'm sure there'd be some other better way of doing this.